# Append multiple csv into a dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to iterate through all files in a folder to open all csv files. After I got all the file directory in a list: a. I need to read them and append them to a dataframe with the same column names.

```
a = [] #empty list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\thaiq\\Week5'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv') and 'Rentals' in file:
            a.append(str(os.path.join(root,file)))

ridedata = pd.DataFrame([]) #empty dataframe

for rides in a:
    file = pd.read_csv(rides,header=0) #open each file in list a
    ridedata.append(file)
```

ridedata return empty, plz help :(

Comment: Unlike python list.append, df.append actually returns a result that needs to be assigned. But aside from that, you should be using pd.concat instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
ridedata = pd.concat([ridedata, file])
```